# Use put request to edit array in array in Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am creating a blog type application using Vue and one of the the things I am trying to do is give users the ability to comment on a post. I am having trouble using my apis PUT request to add the comments to the post. Here is how it is set up to give some context.

postSchema:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userPosted: {
        type: String,
    },
    datePosted: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    course: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    professor: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments:
        [{
            commentedBy: {
                type: String
            },
            commentdate:{
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
            },
            usercomment: {
                type: String
            }
        }],
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
})
```

Post api for PUT request

```
router.put('/:id', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        //find post by id, update using request body, return updated post to 
        Post.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).then(function(){
            //find updated post
            Post.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(post){
                res.send(post)
            }) 
        })
    } catch(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
})
```

comment section page

```
  <form action="" v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
           <!-- comment input field -->
           <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment here...">
           </div>
           <!-- submit button -->
           <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-dark">done</button>
           </div>
      </div>
  </form>
  <hr v-if="isLoggedIn">

  <!-- Comment section -->
  <h4 class="card-title">Comments</h4>
  <!-- single comment -->
  <div class="single-comment" v-for="(comment, i) in post.comments" :key="i">
  <!-- comment information -->
  <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Posted {{moment(comment.commentdate).fromNow()}} by {{comment.commentedBy}}</h6>
   <!-- comment content -->
   <p class="card-text comment-content">{{comment.usercomment}}</p>


</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            post: []
        }
    },
    async created() {
        return this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id)
        .then(res => {
            this.post = res.data
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I modeled it with the comments nested in the post so I am technically editing the post when making a comment. The request work fine in postman so the back-end is set up correctly, but I am having trouble using Vue to accomplish what I want.

This is what the comment section looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment form, you can leverage a local variable in your component to hold the comment while the user is typing it in. We also attach a method to the button to perform an action when clicked:

```
  <form action="" v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
           <!-- comment input field -->
           <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment here..." v-model="currentComment">
           </div>
           <!-- submit button -->
           <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" @click="submitComment">done</button>
           </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Then, in the script portion of the component:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            currentComment: "", // Bucket for holding the comment temporarily
            id: this.$route.params.id,
            post: []
        }
    },
    async created() {
        return this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id)
        .then(res => {
            this.post = res.data
        })
    }
    methods: {
        /* Our submit method for comments */
        async submitComment() {
            this.post.comments.push({
                commentedBy: /*The current user, wherever that is stored*/,
                commentdate: Date.now(),
                usercomment: this.currentComment // Our temporary value
            });
            return this.$http.put('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id, this.post)
            .then(res => {
                /* Do some messaging and cleanup here (like emptying currentComment) */
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You don't show where the current user us coming in from in your example, so `commentedBy` is going to take some work on your part to get the data into the correct place.